# My test are not getting picked up whereas the BUILD is successful

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running pom.xml mvn command to run test cases, but the following appears,
[image]

The BUILD shows successfull but no test gets picked up.The versions are:
mvn version is 3.5.0
junit 4.13
surefire plugin 3.0.0-M5

Comment: First using a very old Maven version (use the most recent version .3.8.6) second define a correct dependency to TestNG because the cucumber output shows TestNG and NOT JUnit .. furthermore use more recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0-M7) and also use more recent versions of plugins.. (maven-install-plugin??))

Comment: @khmarbaise upgraded to maven 3.8.6, now the build fails,  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project CucumberTestNG:

Comment: @khmarbaise The Maven is now 3.8.6, still the Build get Successful but test run =0 failure=0 and skipped =0

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that the T E S T S are running, so you are using a maven goal (`mvn clean install` ?) that runs the test phase, and you are not running with `-DskipTests`

Therefore, pls make sure your tests are located under `src/test/java`.

By convention, name the test classes `MygreatTest` and `AnotherTest` - always ending in -Test.

Also make sure there are no special configuration for surefire plugin that looks for tests of a certain pattern.

Lastly the test methods should be annotated with `@Test`

```
    @Test
    public void aggregatorTest() {
        // ...
    }
```